# Snapshot of particular area of Screen using React Native

Tags: javascript, react-native

****I am developing an application in React Native. One of its feature is I have to take a snapshot of particular area of screen ( Coordinates of the Screen is already Given). Is there any way to do this? I have been searching for this but couldn't found anything useful****

Answer (score 1):

You can try this one. Hope it sufficies your requirement
https://github.com/gre/react-native-view-shot

Comment: No, It's not fulfilling my requirement.